# eRuby - Understanding the Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm on [api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org) trying to read through some of these helpers to build out a form, but I keep getting errors like `undefined method 'merge'`. Unfortunately,

```
number_field(object_name, method, options = {})
    Returns an input tag of type “number”.
```

doesn't help much at all. I've got that `object_name` is the name field for the generated input, but i'm fuzzy on what `method`, and `options` are used for. I just want a series of  labels next to inputs, where clicking the label focuses the input, but all I can get is the first input focused regardless of the label you click.

The syntax I'm using is:

```
<%= f.label :item_data, i.name %> <%= f.number_field :item_data %>
```

`i` is an item from an `each do`. I realize this will give them all the same name, I'm just not sure what else to do about it.

Comment: Can you show the syntax you are using for creating number_field

Answer (score 0):

The `number_field` is a method used to create an html input tag with type "number". `Object_name` is the name of the object of your form (say for instance, `item`). `Method` is the name of the actual field (for instance, `cost`). `Options` are any options you want to pass into the html field, like it being disabled, read-only, giving the tag a class/id, and so forth. If you don't pass in any `options`, the `= {}` means it just defaults to no options.

In conjunction with `form_for`, the syntax changes to something like this:

```
<%= form_for @item do |f| %>
  <%= f.number_field :cost, id: "sample", class: "example" %>
<% end %>
```

Look [at this documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/number_field_tag) for more information on the options you can pass. Yes, it's different syntax, but the options will be the same.

Comment: It seems like no matter what goes into the method field of the number_field, it gives me the merge error.

Comment: It needs to be a field that is in your model/migration. So if you are trying to put "cost" in there and there isn't a "cost" field in your migration, then it will raise an error.

Comment: Where does the `id:` and `class:` come from? Are those optional parts of the options hash? Not quite sure where stuff like that comes from since it's not in the api listing for that method.

Comment: Yeah, that's all part of the optional options hash. I just put them there for examples.

Comment: Ok, does that mean that the options are written like a  `...rest` argument? I would've expected it to look like `{ id: "sample", class: "example" }` or something similar based on the `= {}`.

Comment: The brackets are implied. In some field tags you need the brackets as  there are TWO sets, but in this case since there is only one group it can be left out.

Comment: Ok, so if i'm trying to create a label and input pair, I have `<%= f.label i.name, i.name %> <%= f.number_field i.name %>` to try and get the for/id to match up, but it doesn't like `i.name`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84803/discussion-between-ryan-k-and-evan-ward).